# Debian 9 Stretch install new gsmartcontrol from special repo

Tags: debian, apt, selection

```
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/alex_sh/Debian_9.0/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:alex_sh.list

apt-get update
Ign:1 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/alex_sh/Debian_9.0  InRelease
Get:2 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/alex_sh/Debian_9.0  Release [988 B]
...
Get:5 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/alex_sh/Debian_9.0  Release.gpg [189 B]
...
Ign:5 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/alex_sh/Debian_9.0  Release.gpg
...
Get:10 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/alex_sh/Debian_9.0  Packages [964 B]
Fetched 2,141 B in 5s (389 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/alex_sh/Debian_9.0  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A41001039EC56A71
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/alex_sh/Debian_9.0  Release' is not signed. 
...

apt-get install -t InRelease gsmartcontrol
... The value 'InRelease' is invalid ...
apt-get install -t Release gsmartcontrol
... E: The value 'Release' is invalid ...
apt-get install -t alex_sh gsmartcontrol
...E: The value 'alex_sh' is invalid...
```

What else to do to install gsmartcontrol from alex_sh ???

Comment: Do you get any warning in `apt-get update` like "no public key available for..." ? If so you shouldn't omit this in the question. You can't *only* add a random repository and get it trusted by default

Comment: While it's possible, I don't intend to give an answer to use a repository that is protected neither by a gpg key nor an https transport. You should instead check how to add this key (using `apt-key add`).